# Granting persistent permission to USB host device

Tags: android

I have an app that needs to connect to a USB camera. I want that the user gives the app the permission to access the camera only once and not every time the USB camera is connected.

I tried to use intent filter, as this is the recommended way based on the documentation (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host), but this has the downside that every time the camera connects the apps main activity is started - even if the app was already running. And this is annoying to the users, as they lose all unsaved data and their navigation point in the app.

This is the `AndroidManifest.xml` section:

```xml
<activity
    android:name=".activity.home.HomeActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
        android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
</activity>
```

How can I grant persistent access to the usb device without changing the app status when the device connects?

Comment: Yes, this is a big problem for some use cases. Unfortunately Android won't let you put a meta-data without an action on an activity. It would make sense to have your app say, "I will be using this device, but don't bug me when it attaches". There is `/data/system/users/0/usb_device_manager.xml` and you can add `<settings><preference package="com.example.myapp"><usb-device vendor-id="0x0403" product-id="0x6001"/></preference></settings>`. It will even appear in `dumpsys usb` but I've never noticed this having any effect.